# How can i know values of variables of Console application? (public classes variables )

Tags: c#, console-application

i start program console that prints my results and save the best one in public var in my object of class ,my problem that program take 24 hours and i want to know this var value , program still running i can not stop it now still too much time to finish

is there way to spy on public vars in program

edit: i can not use debugger because i lose data that i get in 24 hours 
it is easy for me to think in debugger but i do not want to wait another 24 hours

Comment: Can you not `Console.WriteLine()` the value on specific intervals? You could also watch via the debugger, but I'm not sure that is something you want to do. I don't believe that the fact that your variables are `public` makes much of a difference. Access modifiers determine what files and classes can access variables and functions of other classes, not whether the value of the variable itself is supposed to be "protected" in some way from other users/developers. If logging them remotely is not enough, send them to a server by polling, HTTP, or Web Sockets every time a value changes.

Comment: the problem it is problem that prints many possibility by Console.WriteLine() that Console can not save that many so my problem that i put the results will appear after 12 * 24 hours , my mistake , and now program stops i want to see first result from 12 results

Comment: It sounds like you really need to reconsider this being a console application or at the very least build out some kind of "interface" to let you interact with the application while the computations are happening in a background thread.

Comment: Is the app built in debug mode?  You can *Debug > Attach to process...* to inspect its variables and, if necessary, its raw memory (harder - but possible).

Comment: how can i attach porcess

Comment: thanks it works that attach it , but no var appear when i set break point like it never been enter

Comment: I still think another option might be to have a separate thread purely for the purpose of sending the variable values, perhaps as JSON, up to a server where they can be stored indefinitely in a database or as a JSON file in the file system. Note that you could use your own computer as the server on `localhost` - which means running your C# program and the server from the same machine. Then you don't have to pay for hosting. You would have to decide whether you want to POST the variable values on a set interval or whether you want to POST them on change.

Comment: thanks all i get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways in which you could do this

Run the program in the debugger.
Maybe not the best way, but it would allow you to spy on any variable

Output the value every xx iterations/minutes to the console.

Output the value every xx iterations/minutes to a log file

Build an interface which can be called from another program to retrieve the information.  For example a REST API interface running in another thread.  Can be done simply with a 3PP such as Embeddio https://unosquare.github.io/embedio/

Comment: i simply want program that allow me to access vars of program without using  debugger because i already have result now after 28 or 24 hours now i just need to catch it , is that possible , i do not want to wait another 24 hours

Comment: You can attach the debugger to a running process.

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: success , but  it still can not see something like break point can not be enter or do not work with attachment